# supervised learning and labels

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) wiki page, I came across with the following phrase.

> When data is not labeled, a supervised learning is not possible, and
>   an unsupervised learning is required

I cannot figure out why supervised learning is not possible?

Appreciate any help to resolve this ambiguity.

Comment: Supervised learning by definition requires data with labels, so, it's by definition? not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference between supervised and unsupervised learning is the following:

In supervised learning you have a set of labelled data, meaning that you have the values of the inputs and the outputs. What you try to achieve with machine learning is to find the **true** relationship between them, what we usually call **the model** in math. There are many different algorithms in machine learning that allow you to obtain a model of the data. The objective that you seek, and how you can use machine learning, is to predict the output given a new input, once you know the model.

In unsupervised learning you don't have the data labelled. You can say that you have the inputs but not the outputs. And the objective is to find some kind of pattern in your data. You can find groups or **clusters** that you think that belong to the same group or output. Here you also have to obtain a model. And again, the objective you seek is to be able to predict the output given a new input.

Finally, going back to your question, if you don't have labels you can not use supervised learning, you have to use unsupervised learning.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is misleading. Here's a better way to look at it:

Whether A problem is **supervised** or **unsupervised** depends on the nature of the problem you're trying to solve. In a **supervised** learning problem there's some **ground truth** you want the algorithm to predict. The **ground truth** could be a discrete label (Classification) or a value in continuous domain (Regression). On the other hand, an **unsupervised** learning problem doesn't try to "predict" some label or value. Rather, it tries to learn a better **representation** or **structure** of the data. Clustering and dimension reduction are both examples of **unsupervised** learning problems.

Now, in order for you to train a supervised learning algorithm, you do need to provide it the ground truth. Lack of labeled data does **NOT** make the problem unsupervised, it only means that you have to spend the effort to obtain the labeled data needed, or else you can't train your algorithm. In reality, it 
is often unrealistic or too expensive to obtain labels/target value for all the data you have. Therefore, there is also a class of **semi-supervised algorithms** which does supervised learning using both labeled and unlabeled data, when certain assumptions apply.

In short, whether a problem is supervised or not depends on the nature of the problem. Some problem requires you to have labeled data in order to train your learning algorithm, and some do not, but having labeled data or not should **NOT** change the nature of the problem you're trying to solve.